# Reconstructing image by inverse filter issue in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I used transfer function 'motion' from `imnoise` in spatial domain.
Now I try to deconvolve it in frequency domain but it not working!!
My codes are here:

```
clc 
close all
clear

display('Welcome to wiener and invert reconstruction image ...');

path = input('Enter pictures path:','s');
info=imfinfo(path);
resolution=info.Width*info.Height;
i=imread(path);

if strcmpi(info.ColorType,'truecolor')
   i=rgb2gray(i);
end

psf=fspecial('motion',70,45);
f=imfilter(single(i),psf);

%f=imnoise(f,'gaussian',0,0.001);

%invert filtering
PQ=paddingsize([info.Height info.Width],'pwr');
F=fft2(  single(f) ,PQ(1),PQ(2)  );
PSF=fft2(  psf ,PQ(1),PQ(2)  );
Fhat=F./PSF;
fhat=ifft2(Fhat);
imshow(fhat(1:info.Height,1:info.Width));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codes are correct but there is some noise amplification .
more detail are at:
http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2007/08/13/image-deblurring-introduction/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Wiener Filter instead of this inverse filter Fhat=F./PSF to reduce the effect of noise amplification.